# SetInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER) and setInputType( InputType.InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD) give out different keyboards

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm trying to make two fields with a password and numbers on the same screen. But for them, a different keyboard is called by default, which does not look pretty. How can this be fixed?

```
setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
```

and

```
setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL)
```

give out different keyboards. How can I fix it?

**1. First input field:**

```
otpField.getEditText().setType(TYPE_FORMATTED_INVISIBLE_MASK);
otpField.getEditText().setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL);
```

[image]

**2. Second input field:**

```
ePINField.getEditText().setType(TYPE_FORMATTED_INVISIBLE_MASK);
ePINField.getEditText().setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple way, but not advised, would be for you to define the two fields as password and make the first `EditText` visible. This doesn't make sense, since the first one is not a password, but it's a way to do what you want (I don't advise, as this would get in the way of the accessibility).

```
otpField.getEditText().setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
otpField.getEditText().setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        
ePINField.getEditText().setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

The `setTransformationMethod()` method will leave the first `EditText` as if it were a "normal" number field, after all it will have the digits visible.

In this way, the two keyboards will be visually identical.

Comment: Good afternoon. Thanks . This is a very interesting way. But how do you get accessibility back? Or how to read the entered data?

Comment: I'm just curious. The method came up with a bang.

Comment: You can take the reference of each `EditText` and call the `setContentDescription()` method. When calling the method you pass a `String` describing exactly what this `EditText` does. See more on the subject on the [official Android page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setContentDescription(java.lang.CharSequence))

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by XML file. you just need to add inputType in your editText.
If you want Password input type then use  `android:inputType="numberPassword"` and if you want plain number text then you can use `android:inputType="number"`.

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"/>
```

Comment: Good afternoon. Thanks for the advice. But all the same, the virtual keyboards of the two EditText are externally different.